# continuity between normed spaces using preimages of open sets

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

I am having some troubles understanding the continuity between normed spaces using preimages of open sets.

[image]

This is the problem I have to solve and it seems incredibly obvious to me. We know that the distance function is continuous, we can bound it by $|d(a,c)|$ so all is good. However, what confuses me is that we want to show that it is in $X$ under the sup norm. Does that mean that we have to show that the distance function under the sup norm is continuous?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to prove that $f_a$ is continuous and bounded. The bounded part is easy:$$f_a(x)=d(x,a)-d(x,c)\leqslant d(x,c)+d(c,a)-d(x,c)=d(c,a)$$and$$f_a(x)=d(x,a)-d(x,c)\geqslant d(x,a)-\bigl(d(x,a)+d(a,c)\bigr)=-d(a,c).$$In order to prove that $f_a$ is continuous at a point $x\in M$, you have to prove that, if $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$d(y,x)<\delta\implies\bigl|f_a(y)-f_a(x)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$But\begin{align}\bigl|f_a(y)-f_a(x)\bigr|&=\bigl|d(y,a)-d(y,c)-d(x,a)+d(x,c)\bigr|\\&\leqslant\bigl|d(y,a)-d(x,a)\bigr|+\bigl|d(y,c)-d(x,c)\bigr|\\&\leqslant2d(y,x)\end{align}So, take $\delta=\frac\varepsilon2$.

Comment: But where does the sup norm come into play?

Comment: @asdf In my answer? Nowhere. My answer proves that each function $f_a$ belongs to the *set* $X$. The fact that the norm that $X$ is endowed with is the sup norm is only used in items (ii) and (iii).